# Firebase Cloud Firestore : Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code and getting an error :

```
Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments
```

**And the code :**

```
private void setAdapter() {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("app/users/" + uid + "/notifications").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d("FragmentNotifications", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("FragmentNotifications", "Error getting notifications.", task.getException());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Hierarchical data structures and subcollections are described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data).  A collection contains documents and a document may contain a subcollection.  The structure is always an alternating pattern of collections and documents.  The documentation contains this description of an example:

> Notice the alternating pattern of collections and documents. Your
>   collections and documents must always follow this pattern. You cannot
>   reference a collection in a collection or a document in a document.

Thus, a valid path to a collection will always have an odd number of segments;  a valid path to a document, an even number.  Since your code is trying to query a collection, the path length of four is invalid.

Comment: Ok, I need something like this : app/users/userId/notifications/{auto-gen-id}/document(The Notification Object). How do I create this sort of a thing in the console or through code?

Comment: @Reim: The console supports creating the structure you want.

Comment: Not that anyone else would be dumb enough to miss this, but one other simple way you can end up with this error is if you run a get on a blank document reference, so check your variable and make sure its not an empty string...

Answer (score 76):

Then you need replace it:

```
db.collection("app/users/" + uid + "/notifications")...
```

with it:

```
db.collection("app").document("users").collection(uid).document("notifications")
```

You're welcome ;)

--**UPDATE 2023**--

If you are using the new Firebase Modular, then remember about the reference:

Firebase requires changing references: *"collectionName" / "documentName" / "collectionName" / "documentId", etc.*

```
setDoc(doc(db, "collectionName", userID, "anotherCollectionName", documentID), ...
```

OR

```
addDoc(collection(this.firestore, "collectionName", documentID), data);
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843735/4654957)

Comment: I want to do this but db.collection doesn't seem to exist on my db instance?

Comment: @lukeet you might be using the modular SDK? It requires a different way of importing the modules.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing collection reference.
i.e db.collection(** This is getting null **).

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue when I provided a wrong entity_Id.

Instead of `dojo/default/datasets/fe67ec58-6208-4234-a4ee-98c5dce4665f`, 
I've provided `fe67ec58-6208-4234-a4ee-98c5dce4665f`and now is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue when I provided an entity_Id that contains the "/" character ( my value was N/A ) when i was trying to read documentReference (DocumentReference docRef2 = fireStoreDb.Collection("Ass").Document(ass.Tel.ToString())
.Collection("vehicules").Document(ve.Immatriculation);).
Here, the value ve.Immatriculation equals to N/A, and that was the problem.

Comment: so what is your solution?

Comment: ensure that you insert data as document Id without the caracter / . For my part, i have a batch in .net (c#) that insert data in FireBase; so i use this line    Immatriculation = car.Immatriculation.Replace("/", "").Replace(".", "").Trim().   to replace the / caractere. Here is the way i use the value as document id :  DocumentReference docRef2 = fireStoreDb.Collection("asss").Document(ass.Tel.ToString())
                                .Collection("vehicules").Document(ve.Immatriculation);

Answer (score 0):

In my case collection name is empty was causing the crash

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("").add(taravih)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
//your data });
```

source https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0