# Firebase Firestore: Update a field of a document in a subcollection while retrieving information

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update a field to a document, while getting the the fields of that document? I am unsure how to do so given my setup. It appears that I can't use .update() with my code as I get an `unresolved reference: update` error.

```
class ReminderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var reminderID: String
   
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder)

        val completeTask: Button = findViewById(R.id.complete_button)
        completeTask.setOnClickListener {
            db.collection("pets").document("vNkkDGAS1oBMpanEXhte").collection("reminders").document(iFdIMKSxJV79Mm64OHwp).get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    val timeStamp = document.get("timestamp") as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                    val millisec = timestamp.seconds * 1000 +timestamp.nanoseconds/1000000
                    val netDate = Date(millisec)
                    val frequency = document.get("frequency").toString()
                    val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    cal.time = netDate
                    
                    val time = Timestamp(cal.timeInMillis)
                    document.update({timestamp: time}) //<- line not working
                }
        }
    }
}
```

pictures of cloud firestore database
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate what's the value of `petID`.

Comment: Thank you for that but you didn't mention what is the value of `petID` in the code. Have you tried using a hard-coded value instead? Does it work that way?

Comment: @AlexMamo is suggesting that you use a hardcoded value for testing purposes. That's part of making a problem as simple as you can for debugging/asking for help.

Comment: You may have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130061/how-to-update-firestore-subcollection-field). Let me know if that helps!

Comment: @IreneSerrano what exactly are you getting here `document.update({timestamp: time}) //<- line not working`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad, the error im getting is 

unresolved reference: update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `document` is of type `DocumentSnapshot` class and you can't update with this object. Update can only be done from `DocumentReference` class object. You need to update the implementation for updating the document.

Comment: With this comment and the following [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682615/14375385) I was able to come up with a working answer