# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but cities/SF/landmarks has 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am following the [firestore tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_14)

First they instruct me to seed the database with

```js
    import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

    const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");

    await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "SF"), {
        name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
        capital: false, population: 860000,
        regions: ["west_coast", "norcal"] });
    await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "LA"), {
        name: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", country: "USA",
        capital: false, population: 3900000,
        regions: ["west_coast", "socal"] });
    await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "DC"), {
        name: "Washington, D.C.", state: null, country: "USA",
        capital: true, population: 680000,
        regions: ["east_coast"] });
    await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "TOK"), {
        name: "Tokyo", state: null, country: "Japan",
        capital: true, population: 9000000,
        regions: ["kanto", "honshu"] });
    await setDoc(doc(citiesRef, "BJ"), {
        name: "Beijing", state: null, country: "China",
        capital: true, population: 21500000,
        regions: ["jingjinji", "hebei"] });
```

Later in the tutorial they instruct me to run this code to create some sub-collections

```js
    import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";  

    const citiesRef = collection(db, 'cities');

    await Promise.all([
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'SF', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Golden Gate Bridge',
            type: 'bridge'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'SF', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Legion of Honor',
            type: 'museum'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'LA', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Griffith Park',
            type: 'park'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'LA', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'The Getty',
            type: 'museum'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'DC', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Lincoln Memorial',
            type: 'memorial'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'DC', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'National Air and Space Museum',
            type: 'museum'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'TOK', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Ueno Park',
            type: 'park'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'TOK', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'National Museum of Nature and Science',
            type: 'museum'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'BJ', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Jingshan Park',
            type: 'park'
        }),
        setDoc(doc(citiesRef, 'BJ', 'landmarks'), {
            name: 'Beijing Ancient Observatory',
            type: 'museum'
        })
    ]);
```

However, this results in the error

> errors.ts:94 Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but cities/SF/landmarks has 3.

Anyone know what the reason for that is?

Comment: This might be helpful too: [Firestore: What's the pattern for adding new data in Web v9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987326/firestore-whats-the-pattern-for-adding-new-data-in-web-v9/68987445#68987445).

Comment: Do you really need all those codes to demonstrate your question?

Answer (score 20):

That looks like a mistake in the sample code. Since `citiesRef` is a collection reference, so is `doc(citiesRef, 'SF', 'landmarks')`, and you can't call `setDoc` on a collection reference.

Call `addDoc` instead of `setDoc` and `collection` instead of `doc` and things should work much better:

```
addDoc(collection(citiesRef, 'SF', 'landmarks'), {
    name: 'Golden Gate Bridge',
    type: 'bridge'
}),
```

**Update 16-06-2022:** That documentation page has been fixed and now uses `addDoc()` instead of `setDoc()` and `collection()` instead of `doc()`.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and found a solution after many trials and errors, so decided to post the answer: the problem is lies in the doc reference. Firebase requires changing references: collection / document / collection / document, etc. In my case I was referencing collection/document/document and that gave me this error.

wrong way:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "collectionName", userID, documentID), ...
```

fixed (adding another collection in between):

```
setDoc(doc(db, "collectionName", userID, "anotherCollectionName", documentID), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[setDoc]([doc](citiesRef, 'DC', 'landmarks'), {
    name: 'National Air and Space Museum',
    type: 'museum'
}),
```

change your setDoc to addDoc and your doc to collection this should address it.
if your are referencing a collection don't used doc instead used collection

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, but still wanted to use the `setDoc` instead of `addDoc`.

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even
> number of segments, but collection has 1.

The reason of my error was that when I called `doc(db, 'collection', id)` and the `id` was being an empty string `''`.

I just added a check before, so that the collectionId is not undefined or empty string.

Here's my snippet:

```js
export const addPlayedGame = async (collectionId: string) => {
  try {
    if(!collectionId) return false;

    const collectionRef = doc(firebase.db, 'collection', collectionId);

    const updateObject = {
     ...
    };

    await setDoc(collectionRef, updateObject, { merge: true });

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The discussion were started long ago but i know the problem and no one gave that answer, so i would write. The problem is: "doc()" function expect to take two arguments. First argument is the collection reference(example: collection(db, "i am a collection") ), second argument is the id of the document which you want to pick.

For Example:

```
let firestore = getFirestore();

let colref = collection(firestore, "i am a collection");

let document = doc(colref, "id of the document");
```

So for your example: the "doc()" function already taken the collection name from your "citiesRef" variable. You shouldn't put 3 arguments unless you don't want to put your "citiesRef"s arguments inside to the "doc()" function's arguments.