# Getting "Invalid doc ref. Doc ref must have an even number of segments," Error when writing batch doc to Firebase Firestore V9 Angularfire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I tried using writeBatch() to write documents in subcollections.

I followed the Fireabase [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and came up with the script:

```
const batch = writeBatch(this.db);

const ref = doc(this.db, 'collection/document/collection1/document/collection2');

batch.set(ref, data);

await batch.commit()
```

"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but collection/document/collection1/document/collection2 has 5."

I read in one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639058/firebase-cloud-firestore-invalid-collection-reference-collection-references-m) that The path to a document has an even number of segments. While the path to a collection has odd. So, I decided to try using collection instead.

```
const batch = writeBatch(this.db);

const ref = collection(this.db, 'collection/document/collection1/document/collection2');

batch.set(ref, data);

await batch.commit()
```

but this time, there is a type error:

"Argument of type 'CollectionReference' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found a solution in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) that you can create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. Like so:

```
const batch = writeBatch(this.db);

const ref = collection(this.db, 'collection/document/collection1/document/collection2');

batch.set(doc(ref), data);

await batch.commit()
```